# Find the x values along 2 lines if the y coordinates along the lines are known

Tags: angular, math, svg, polygon

[image]

[All coordinates of the polygon are known]
here for the particular Y value, I need to calculate the x range that is in the fill of the polygon but now I am searching for every point of x  for y and check whether it is in the fill or not, can anyone suggest a better solution for this.

//////////////////////////UPDATE//////////////////
[image]
Here I can calculate the bounding box for the polygon so that is BBox in SVG .
It has the attributes of

> startPositionx,y and width, and height

.**
So here is my algorithm to compute all the points in the algorithm.

```
x=this.startPosition.x;
for(y:this.startPosition.y;y<=(this.startPosition.y+height);y++)
{
If(polygon.isPointInFill(x,y))
{
// return the point is inside the polygon
}
X++;
If(x>(this.startPosition.x+width))
{
x=this.startPosition.x
}
```

Comment: Better solution than what?

Comment: I am checking each and every point in the  polygons that is between the maximum and minimum of x and Y so it takes more time to execute , so I am searching for a solution if we already know the polygon area x range for the y  the time will be reduced

Comment: yes we need additional information but i can get all the points of the vertices cant i do with this information

Comment: Please show the solution you have, then it is easier to discuss how to improve it, i.e. make an [mre]. Also tag the programming language you are using for it.

Comment: I think I now got the details of your diagram.... If all coordinates (X and Y) of all points are known and also the y coordinate of the black line, then all needed information is available. Please make sure that your MRE contains all that information in suitable variables, to make it available for calculations.

Comment: It boils down to identifying the two edges which intersect with the black line and then calculate the coordinates of the two intersections. Doesn't it?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the polygon is convex? Otherwise there might be more than two intersections and more than one range on the black line. What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: I have updated the question with an algorithm that I am using now, but I did not consider the vertices of the polygon  and the polygon can be  convex or concave and I only know the vertices of the polygon no other angles of the polygon

Comment: yes I need to calculate the intersection of two points in the black line

Comment: Tag a programming language to attract the right people.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 window.onload = function() {
      console.log(paintSvgToCanvas(document.getElementById("ele01")));
    };

    function paintSvgToCanvas(svgEle) {
      let parsePattern = new RegExp(/(M|L)\d+\s\d+/gi);
      let parsePatternXY = new RegExp(/\d+/gi);
      let pointList = [];
      let minX = 0;
      let maxX = 0;
      let minY = 0;
      let maxY = 0;
      switch (svgEle.tagName) {
        case "path":
          let parseData = svgEle.getAttribute("d");
          parseData.match(parsePattern).forEach(function(item, idx) {
            let temp = item.match(parsePatternXY);
            temp[0] = parseFloat(temp[0]);
            temp[1] = parseFloat(temp[1]);
            if (idx === 0) {
              minX = temp[0];
              maxX = temp[0];
              minY = temp[1];
              maxY = temp[1];
            } else {
              if (temp[0] < minX) {
                minX = temp[0];
              } else if (temp[0] > maxX) {
                maxX = temp[0];
              }
              if (temp[1] < minY) {
                minY = temp[1];
              } else if (temp[1] > maxY) {
                maxY = temp[1];
              }
            }
            pointList.push(temp);
          });
        default:
          break;
      }
      return {
        minX: minX,
        maxX: maxX,
        minY: minY,
        maxY: maxY
      };
```

It's my code. get range of svg path element.

Comment: thank you for your response , this function will return the maximum and minimum value of path element but I need to calculate the maximum and minimum values for a particular value of y  for x